# How can I write a loop that reads in all the files (2 file per cell) and then apply function

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop, dplyr

I have 76 neurons, and 2 files (.dat format) that correspond to each neuron (1_perDend_counts.dat and 1_perDend.dat) so 152 files in total. the number prefix changes according to cell ID and the cell IDs are noncontinuous as in they do not follow numeric order.

i would like to have a loop that reads in all the files and combine them into 1 new data frame with the columns "cell_ID, tuft avg, basal avg, oblique avg, prim avg, tuft order avg, basal order avg, tuft count, basal count, oblique count" . All the averages are cell_ID specific.

I would like to perform this data manipulation but for all 76 neurons.

```
count1 <- read.table("1_perDend_counts.dat", header = T)
morph1 <- read.table("1_perDend.dat", header = T)

morph1$order <- as.numeric(morph1$order)

avg_data <- morph1 %>%
  group_by(cell_id) %>%
  mutate(tuft_avg = mean(length[dend_type == "tuft"]),
         basal_avg = mean(length[dend_type == "basal"]),
         oblique_avg = mean(length[dend_type == "oblique"]),
         prim_avg = mean(length[dend_type == "primary"]),
         tuft_order_avg = mean(order[dend_type == "tuft"]),
         basal_order_avg = mean(order[dend_type == "basal"])) %>%
  slice(1) %>%
  select(-order, -dend_type, -length)

count1 <- spread(count1, dend_type, count)
colnames(count1) <- c("cell_id", "tuft_count", "basal_count", "oblique_count")

all <- merge(avg_data, count1, by = "cell_id", all = TRUE)
```

Comment: The `list.files` function returns file names of a path with a given pattern. You can use that to get the file names and loop over them.

Comment: I'd start with `list.files()` looking for the pattern "_counts.dat" - this would allow you to get a list of files from which you can strip the neuron number, and use that to apply your function to each in turn.

Comment: You might find `vroom` convenient, which will read in and rowbind all text-files with tabular data from a given directory plus adding the originating filename in a separate column if desired: https://vroom.r-lib.org/articles/vroom.html#reading-multiple-files